# How can I remove rows containing duplicates without looping?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a somewhat sophisticated operation that I need to complete; I need to check for a certain value in a row, say the word "Special", and then 'cut' that entire row from the original sheet and paste it by no particular order. However, I also need to check for duplicates in this sheet and remove both the original and duplicate row; seemingly, both of these operations require loops to check an entire columns worth of values in a sheet that may be 250+ values tall, and that ends up being really slow.

So, in short, how can I check for these values and do the required action on them without using loops? I am aware that there is an excel FIND() function but I am having trouble implementing this to note down repeated values.

Comment: As to the copy paste.  After you remove the duplicates, filter the data, copy and paste the visible range.  No loops needed.

Comment: 250 rows is not large - if your code is slow it would help to include it in your question.  There are many questions already posted here which address various ways of speeding up row deletion, but without seeing what you're currently doing it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: @ScottCraner the built-in RemoveDuplicates will leave one record behind. The OP wants to remove original AND duplicate, so RemoveDuplicates won't work.

Comment: @teylyn missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am aware that you prefer to avoid looping, but this method should be quick *(especially for you only running against 250 rows)*.

You will loop each cell in your range, using the `rng.Find()`. The trick is to look after the current cell's range in your method, then compare `cel`'s address with the address of `.Find()`. If the addresses match, then there is no duplicate. However, if the addresses are different then you know there is another value somewhere in that range.

You will place all of your dupes in a range object that you will later delete all in a single sweep.

You failed to provide your current code, so I am going to assume you are using the worksheet index `(1)` and column A. If either is not correct, then you will need to make a few minor adjustments.

```
Sub RemoveAllDupes()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow(ws))

    Dim delRng As Range, cel As Range, tRng As Range
    For Each cel In rng.Cells
        Set tRng = rng.Find(cel.Value, cel, xlValues, xlWhole)
        If tRng.Address <> cel.Address Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = Union(cel, tRng)
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(delRng, cel, tRng)
            End If
        End If
        Set tRng = Nothing
    Next cel

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub

Function lastRow(ws As Worksheet, Optional col As Variant = 1) As Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

As you can see, we've `Union()`'d both `cel` (which is the loop's current cell) and `tRng` (which is the alternate cell). This ensures that both the original and dupe target are both removed when `delRng` is deleted.

Since we are looping the entire range and always looking forward, it's not necessary to find all instances of a dupe at once *(although it may make it ever-so-slightly more efficient to ignore cells already checked)*.